# manipulate multiple variables in a data frame

Tags: r, dataframe

How to shorten the following codes? I feel it's so repetitive and lengthy and perhaps can be shortened. Not sure how to select those variables and do the recoding like this in a succinct way. Any help is welcome!

```
data_France$X.1CTP2[data_France$X.1CTP2>7.01 | data_France$X.1CTP2<0.99]<-NA
data_France$X.1CTP3[data_France$X.1CTP3>7.01 | data_France$X.1CTP3<0.99]<-NA
data_France$X.1CTP4[data_France$X.1CTP4>7.01 | data_France$X.1CTP4<0.99]<-NA
data_France$X.1CTP5[data_France$X.1CTP5>7.01 | data_France$X.1CTP5<0.99]<-NA
data_France$X.1CTP6[data_France$X.1CTP6>7.01 | data_France$X.1CTP6<0.99]<-NA
data_France$X.1CTP7[data_France$X.1CTP7>7.01 | data_France$X.1CTP7<0.99]<-NA
data_France$X.1CTP8[data_France$X.1CTP8>7.01 | data_France$X.1CTP8<0.99]<-NA
data_France$X.1CTP9[data_France$X.1CTP9>7.01 | data_France$X.1CTP9<0.99]<-NA
data_France$X.1CTP10[data_France$X.1CTP10>7.01 | data_France$X.1CTP10<0.99]<-NA
data_France$X.1CTP11[data_France$X.1CTP11>7.01 | data_France$X.1CTP11<0.99]<-NA
data_France$X.1CTP12[data_France$X.1CTP12>7.01 | data_France$X.1CTP12<0.99]<-NA
data_France$X.1CTP13[data_France$X.1CTP13>7.01 | data_France$X.1CTP13<0.99]<-NA
data_France$X.1CTP14[data_France$X.1CTP14>7.01 | data_France$X.1CTP14<0.99]<-NA
data_France$X.1CTP15[data_France$X.1CTP15>7.01 | data_France$X.1CTP15<0.99]<-NA

data_France$X.2CTP1[data_France$X.2CTP1>7.01 | data_France$X.2CTP1<0.99]<-NA
data_France$X.2CTP3[data_France$X.2CTP3>7.01 | data_France$X.2CTP3<0.99]<-NA
data_France$X.2CTP4[data_France$X.2CTP4>7.01 | data_France$X.2CTP4<0.99]<-NA
data_France$X.2CTP5[data_France$X.2CTP5>7.01 | data_France$X.2CTP5<0.99]<-NA
data_France$X.2CTP6[data_France$X.2CTP6>7.01 | data_France$X.2CTP6<0.99]<-NA
data_France$X.2CTP7[data_France$X.2CTP7>7.01 | data_France$X.2CTP7<0.99]<-NA
data_France$X.2CTP8[data_France$X.2CTP8>7.01 | data_France$X.2CTP8<0.99]<-NA
data_France$X.2CTP9[data_France$X.2CTP9>7.01 | data_France$X.2CTP9<0.99]<-NA
data_France$X.2CTP10[data_France$X.2CTP10>7.01 | data_France$X.2CTP10<0.99]<-NA
data_France$X.2CTP11[data_France$X.2CTP11>7.01 | data_France$X.2CTP11<0.99]<-NA
data_France$X.2CTP12[data_France$X.2CTP12>7.01 | data_France$X.2CTP12<0.99]<-NA
data_France$X.2CTP13[data_France$X.2CTP13>7.01 | data_France$X.2CTP13<0.99]<-NA
data_France$X.2CTP14[data_France$X.2CTP14>7.01 | data_France$X.2CTP14<0.99]<-NA
data_France$X.2CTP15[data_France$X.2CTP15>7.01 | data_France$X.2CTP15<0.99]<-NA

data_France$X.3CTP1[data_France$X.3CTP1>7.01 | data_France$X.3CTP1<0.99]<-NA
data_France$X.3CTP2[data_France$X.3CTP2>7.01 | data_France$X.3CTP2<0.99]<-NA
data_France$X.3CTP4[data_France$X.3CTP4>7.01 | data_France$X.3CTP4<0.99]<-NA
data_France$X.3CTP5[data_France$X.3CTP5>7.01 | data_France$X.3CTP5<0.99]<-NA
data_France$X.3CTP6[data_France$X.3CTP6>7.01 | data_France$X.3CTP6<0.99]<-NA
data_France$X.3CTP7[data_France$X.3CTP7>7.01 | data_France$X.3CTP7<0.99]<-NA
data_France$X.3CTP8[data_France$X.3CTP8>7.01 | data_France$X.3CTP8<0.99]<-NA
data_France$X.3CTP9[data_France$X.3CTP9>7.01 | data_France$X.3CTP9<0.99]<-NA
data_France$X.3CTP10[data_France$X.3CTP10>7.01 | data_France$X.3CTP10<0.99]<-NA
data_France$X.3CTP11[data_France$X.3CTP11>7.01 | data_France$X.3CTP11<0.99]<-NA
data_France$X.3CTP12[data_France$X.3CTP12>7.01 | data_France$X.3CTP12<0.99]<-NA
data_France$X.3CTP13[data_France$X.3CTP13>7.01 | data_France$X.3CTP13<0.99]<-NA
data_France$X.3CTP14[data_France$X.3CTP14>7.01 | data_France$X.3CTP14<0.99]<-NA
data_France$X.3CTP15[data_France$X.3CTP15>7.01 | data_France$X.3CTP15<0.99]<-NA

data_France$X.4CTP1[data_France$X.4CTP1>7.01 | data_France$X.4CTP1<0.99]<-NA
data_France$X.4CTP2[data_France$X.4CTP2>7.01 | data_France$X.4CTP2<0.99]<-NA
data_France$X.4CTP3[data_France$X.4CTP3>7.01 | data_France$X.4CTP3<0.99]<-NA
data_France$X.4CTP5[data_France$X.4CTP5>7.01 | data_France$X.4CTP5<0.99]<-NA
data_France$X.4CTP6[data_France$X.4CTP6>7.01 | data_France$X.4CTP6<0.99]<-NA
data_France$X.4CTP7[data_France$X.4CTP7>7.01 | data_France$X.4CTP7<0.99]<-NA
data_France$X.4CTP8[data_France$X.4CTP8>7.01 | data_France$X.4CTP8<0.99]<-NA
data_France$X.4CTP9[data_France$X.4CTP9>7.01 | data_France$X.4CTP9<0.99]<-NA
data_France$X.4CTP10[data_France$X.4CTP10>7.01 | data_France$X.4CTP10<0.99]<-NA
data_France$X.4CTP11[data_France$X.4CTP11>7.01 | data_France$X.4CTP11<0.99]<-NA
data_France$X.4CTP12[data_France$X.4CTP12>7.01 | data_France$X.4CTP12<0.99]<-NA
data_France$X.4CTP13[data_France$X.4CTP13>7.01 | data_France$X.4CTP13<0.99]<-NA
data_France$X.4CTP14[data_France$X.4CTP14>7.01 | data_France$X.4CTP14<0.99]<-NA
data_France$X.4CTP15[data_France$X.4CTP15>7.01 | data_France$X.4CTP15<0.99]<-NA


data_France$X.5CTP1[data_France$X.5CTP1>7.01 | data_France$X.5CTP1<0.99]<-NA
data_France$X.5CTP2[data_France$X.5CTP2>7.01 | data_France$X.5CTP2<0.99]<-NA
data_France$X.5CTP3[data_France$X.5CTP3>7.01 | data_France$X.5CTP3<0.99]<-NA
data_France$X.5CTP4[data_France$X.5CTP4>7.01 | data_France$X.5CTP4<0.99]<-NA
data_France$X.5CTP6[data_France$X.5CTP6>7.01 | data_France$X.5CTP6<0.99]<-NA
data_France$X.5CTP7[data_France$X.5CTP7>7.01 | data_France$X.5CTP7<0.99]<-NA
data_France$X.5CTP8[data_France$X.5CTP8>7.01 | data_France$X.5CTP8<0.99]<-NA
data_France$X.5CTP9[data_France$X.5CTP9>7.01 | data_France$X.5CTP9<0.99]<-NA
data_France$X.5CTP10[data_France$X.5CTP10>7.01 | data_France$X.5CTP10<0.99]<-NA
data_France$X.5CTP11[data_France$X.5CTP11>7.01 | data_France$X.5CTP11<0.99]<-NA
data_France$X.5CTP12[data_France$X.5CTP12>7.01 | data_France$X.5CTP12<0.99]<-NA
data_France$X.5CTP13[data_France$X.5CTP13>7.01 | data_France$X.5CTP13<0.99]<-NA
data_France$X.5CTP14[data_France$X.5CTP14>7.01 | data_France$X.5CTP14<0.99]<-NA
data_France$X.5CTP15[data_France$X.5CTP15>7.01 | data_France$X.5CTP15<0.99]<-NA

data_France$X.6CTP1[data_France$X.6CTP1>7.01 | data_France$X.6CTP1<0.99]<-NA
data_France$X.6CTP2[data_France$X.6CTP2>7.01 | data_France$X.6CTP2<0.99]<-NA
data_France$X.6CTP3[data_France$X.6CTP3>7.01 | data_France$X.6CTP3<0.99]<-NA
data_France$X.6CTP4[data_France$X.6CTP4>7.01 | data_France$X.6CTP4<0.99]<-NA
data_France$X.6CTP5[data_France$X.6CTP5>7.01 | data_France$X.6CTP5<0.99]<-NA
data_France$X.6CTP7[data_France$X.6CTP7>7.01 | data_France$X.6CTP7<0.99]<-NA
data_France$X.6CTP8[data_France$X.6CTP8>7.01 | data_France$X.6CTP8<0.99]<-NA
data_France$X.6CTP9[data_France$X.6CTP9>7.01 | data_France$X.6CTP9<0.99]<-NA
data_France$X.6CTP10[data_France$X.6CTP10>7.01 | data_France$X.6CTP10<0.99]<-NA
data_France$X.6CTP11[data_France$X.6CTP11>7.01 | data_France$X.6CTP11<0.99]<-NA
data_France$X.6CTP12[data_France$X.6CTP12>7.01 | data_France$X.6CTP12<0.99]<-NA
data_France$X.6CTP13[data_France$X.6CTP13>7.01 | data_France$X.6CTP13<0.99]<-NA
data_France$X.6CTP14[data_France$X.6CTP14>7.01 | data_France$X.6CTP14<0.99]<-NA
data_France$X.6CTP15[data_France$X.6CTP15>7.01 | data_France$X.6CTP15<0.99]<-NA


data_France$X.7CTP1[data_France$X.7CTP1>7.01 | data_France$X.7CTP1<0.99]<-NA
data_France$X.7CTP2[data_France$X.7CTP2>7.01 | data_France$X.7CTP2<0.99]<-NA
data_France$X.7CTP3[data_France$X.7CTP3>7.01 | data_France$X.7CTP3<0.99]<-NA
data_France$X.7CTP4[data_France$X.7CTP4>7.01 | data_France$X.7CTP4<0.99]<-NA
data_France$X.7CTP5[data_France$X.7CTP5>7.01 | data_France$X.7CTP5<0.99]<-NA
data_France$X.7CTP6[data_France$X.7CTP6>7.01 | data_France$X.7CTP6<0.99]<-NA
data_France$X.7CTP8[data_France$X.7CTP8>7.01 | data_France$X.7CTP8<0.99]<-NA
data_France$X.7CTP9[data_France$X.7CTP9>7.01 | data_France$X.7CTP9<0.99]<-NA
data_France$X.7CTP10[data_France$X.7CTP10>7.01 | data_France$X.7CTP10<0.99]<-NA
data_France$X.7CTP11[data_France$X.7CTP11>7.01 | data_France$X.7CTP11<0.99]<-NA
data_France$X.7CTP12[data_France$X.7CTP12>7.01 | data_France$X.7CTP12<0.99]<-NA
data_France$X.7CTP13[data_France$X.7CTP13>7.01 | data_France$X.7CTP13<0.99]<-NA
data_France$X.7CTP14[data_France$X.7CTP14>7.01 | data_France$X.7CTP14<0.99]<-NA
data_France$X.7CTP15[data_France$X.7CTP15>7.01 | data_France$X.7CTP15<0.99]<-NA


data_France$X.8CTP1[data_France$X.8CTP1>7.01 | data_France$X.8CTP1<0.99]<-NA
data_France$X.8CTP2[data_France$X.8CTP2>7.01 | data_France$X.8CTP2<0.99]<-NA
data_France$X.8CTP3[data_France$X.8CTP3>7.01 | data_France$X.8CTP3<0.99]<-NA
data_France$X.8CTP4[data_France$X.8CTP4>7.01 | data_France$X.8CTP4<0.99]<-NA
data_France$X.8CTP5[data_France$X.8CTP5>7.01 | data_France$X.8CTP5<0.99]<-NA
data_France$X.8CTP6[data_France$X.8CTP6>7.01 | data_France$X.8CTP6<0.99]<-NA
data_France$X.8CTP7[data_France$X.8CTP7>7.01 | data_France$X.8CTP7<0.99]<-NA
data_France$X.8CTP9[data_France$X.8CTP9>7.01 | data_France$X.8CTP9<0.99]<-NA
data_France$X.8CTP10[data_France$X.8CTP10>7.01 | data_France$X.8CTP10<0.99]<-NA
data_France$X.8CTP11[data_France$X.8CTP11>7.01 | data_France$X.8CTP11<0.99]<-NA
data_France$X.8CTP12[data_France$X.8CTP12>7.01 | data_France$X.8CTP12<0.99]<-NA
data_France$X.8CTP13[data_France$X.8CTP13>7.01 | data_France$X.8CTP13<0.99]<-NA
data_France$X.8CTP14[data_France$X.8CTP14>7.01 | data_France$X.8CTP14<0.99]<-NA
data_France$X.8CTP15[data_France$X.8CTP15>7.01 | data_France$X.8CTP15<0.99]<-NA


data_France$X.9CTP1[data_France$X.9CTP1>7.01 | data_France$X.9CTP1<0.99]<-NA
data_France$X.9CTP2[data_France$X.9CTP2>7.01 | data_France$X.9CTP2<0.99]<-NA
data_France$X.9CTP3[data_France$X.9CTP3>7.01 | data_France$X.9CTP3<0.99]<-NA
data_France$X.9CTP4[data_France$X.9CTP4>7.01 | data_France$X.9CTP4<0.99]<-NA
data_France$X.9CTP5[data_France$X.9CTP5>7.01 | data_France$X.9CTP5<0.99]<-NA
data_France$X.9CTP6[data_France$X.9CTP6>7.01 | data_France$X.9CTP6<0.99]<-NA
data_France$X.9CTP7[data_France$X.9CTP7>7.01 | data_France$X.9CTP7<0.99]<-NA
data_France$X.9CTP8[data_France$X.9CTP8>7.01 | data_France$X.9CTP8<0.99]<-NA
data_France$X.9CTP10[data_France$X.9CTP10>7.01 | data_France$X.9CTP10<0.99]<-NA
data_France$X.9CTP11[data_France$X.9CTP11>7.01 | data_France$X.9CTP11<0.99]<-NA
data_France$X.9CTP12[data_France$X.9CTP12>7.01 | data_France$X.9CTP12<0.99]<-NA
data_France$X.9CTP13[data_France$X.9CTP13>7.01 | data_France$X.9CTP13<0.99]<-NA
data_France$X.9CTP14[data_France$X.9CTP14>7.01 | data_France$X.9CTP14<0.99]<-NA
data_France$X.9CTP15[data_France$X.9CTP15>7.01 | data_France$X.9CTP15<0.99]<-NA


data_France$X.10CTP1[data_France$X.10CTP1>7.01 | data_France$X.10CTP1<0.99]<-NA
data_France$X.10CTP2[data_France$X.10CTP2>7.01 | data_France$X.10CTP2<0.99]<-NA
data_France$X.10CTP3[data_France$X.10CTP3>7.01 | data_France$X.10CTP3<0.99]<-NA
data_France$X.10CTP4[data_France$X.10CTP4>7.01 | data_France$X.10CTP4<0.99]<-NA
data_France$X.10CTP5[data_France$X.10CTP5>7.01 | data_France$X.10CTP5<0.99]<-NA
data_France$X.10CTP6[data_France$X.10CTP6>7.01 | data_France$X.10CTP6<0.99]<-NA
data_France$X.10CTP7[data_France$X.10CTP7>7.01 | data_France$X.10CTP7<0.99]<-NA
data_France$X.10CTP8[data_France$X.10CTP8>7.01 | data_France$X.10CTP8<0.99]<-NA
data_France$X.10CTP9[data_France$X.10CTP9>7.01 | data_France$X.10CTP9<0.99]<-NA
data_France$X.10CTP11[data_France$X.10CTP11>7.01 | data_France$X.10CTP11<0.99]<-NA
data_France$X.10CTP12[data_France$X.10CTP12>7.01 | data_France$X.10CTP12<0.99]<-NA
data_France$X.10CTP13[data_France$X.10CTP13>7.01 | data_France$X.10CTP13<0.99]<-NA
data_France$X.10CTP14[data_France$X.10CTP14>7.01 | data_France$X.10CTP14<0.99]<-NA
data_France$X.10CTP15[data_France$X.10CTP15>7.01 | data_France$X.10CTP15<0.99]<-NA


data_France$X.11CTP1[data_France$X.11CTP1>7.01 | data_France$X.11CTP1<0.99]<-NA
data_France$X.11CTP2[data_France$X.11CTP2>7.01 | data_France$X.11CTP2<0.99]<-NA
data_France$X.11CTP3[data_France$X.11CTP3>7.01 | data_France$X.11CTP3<0.99]<-NA
data_France$X.11CTP4[data_France$X.11CTP4>7.01 | data_France$X.11CTP4<0.99]<-NA
data_France$X.11CTP5[data_France$X.11CTP5>7.01 | data_France$X.11CTP5<0.99]<-NA
data_France$X.11CTP6[data_France$X.11CTP6>7.01 | data_France$X.11CTP6<0.99]<-NA
data_France$X.11CTP7[data_France$X.11CTP7>7.01 | data_France$X.11CTP7<0.99]<-NA
data_France$X.11CTP8[data_France$X.11CTP8>7.01 | data_France$X.11CTP8<0.99]<-NA
data_France$X.11CTP9[data_France$X.11CTP9>7.01 | data_France$X.11CTP9<0.99]<-NA
data_France$X.11CTP10[data_France$X.11CTP10>7.01 | data_France$X.11CTP10<0.99]<-NA
data_France$X.11CTP12[data_France$X.11CTP12>7.01 | data_France$X.11CTP12<0.99]<-NA
data_France$X.11CTP13[data_France$X.11CTP13>7.01 | data_France$X.11CTP13<0.99]<-NA
data_France$X.11CTP14[data_France$X.11CTP14>7.01 | data_France$X.11CTP14<0.99]<-NA
data_France$X.11CTP15[data_France$X.11CTP15>7.01 | data_France$X.11CTP15<0.99]<-NA


data_France$X.12CTP1[data_France$X.12CTP1>7.01 | data_France$X.12CTP1<0.99]<-NA
data_France$X.12CTP2[data_France$X.12CTP2>7.01 | data_France$X.12CTP2<0.99]<-NA
data_France$X.12CTP3[data_France$X.12CTP3>7.01 | data_France$X.12CTP3<0.99]<-NA
data_France$X.12CTP4[data_France$X.12CTP4>7.01 | data_France$X.12CTP4<0.99]<-NA
data_France$X.12CTP5[data_France$X.12CTP5>7.01 | data_France$X.12CTP5<0.99]<-NA
data_France$X.12CTP6[data_France$X.12CTP6>7.01 | data_France$X.12CTP6<0.99]<-NA
data_France$X.12CTP7[data_France$X.12CTP7>7.01 | data_France$X.12CTP7<0.99]<-NA
data_France$X.12CTP8[data_France$X.12CTP8>7.01 | data_France$X.12CTP8<0.99]<-NA
data_France$X.12CTP9[data_France$X.12CTP9>7.01 | data_France$X.12CTP9<0.99]<-NA
data_France$X.12CTP10[data_France$X.12CTP10>7.01 | data_France$X.12CTP10<0.99]<-NA
data_France$X.12CTP11[data_France$X.12CTP11>7.01 | data_France$X.12CTP11<0.99]<-NA
data_France$X.12CTP13[data_France$X.12CTP13>7.01 | data_France$X.12CTP13<0.99]<-NA
data_France$X.12CTP14[data_France$X.12CTP14>7.01 | data_France$X.12CTP14<0.99]<-NA
data_France$X.12CTP15[data_France$X.12CTP15>7.01 | data_France$X.12CTP15<0.99]<-NA



data_France$X.13CTP1[data_France$X.13CTP1>7.01 | data_France$X.13CTP1<0.99]<-NA
data_France$X.13CTP2[data_France$X.13CTP2>7.01 | data_France$X.13CTP2<0.99]<-NA
data_France$X.13CTP3[data_France$X.13CTP3>7.01 | data_France$X.13CTP3<0.99]<-NA
data_France$X.13CTP4[data_France$X.13CTP4>7.01 | data_France$X.13CTP4<0.99]<-NA
data_France$X.13CTP5[data_France$X.13CTP5>7.01 | data_France$X.13CTP5<0.99]<-NA
data_France$X.13CTP6[data_France$X.13CTP6>7.01 | data_France$X.13CTP6<0.99]<-NA
data_France$X.13CTP7[data_France$X.13CTP7>7.01 | data_France$X.13CTP7<0.99]<-NA
data_France$X.13CTP8[data_France$X.13CTP8>7.01 | data_France$X.13CTP8<0.99]<-NA
data_France$X.13CTP9[data_France$X.13CTP9>7.01 | data_France$X.13CTP9<0.99]<-NA
data_France$X.13CTP10[data_France$X.13CTP10>7.01 | data_France$X.13CTP10<0.99]<-NA
data_France$X.13CTP11[data_France$X.13CTP11>7.01 | data_France$X.13CTP11<0.99]<-NA
data_France$X.13CTP12[data_France$X.13CTP12>7.01 | data_France$X.13CTP12<0.99]<-NA
data_France$X.13CTP14[data_France$X.13CTP14>7.01 | data_France$X.13CTP14<0.99]<-NA
data_France$X.13CTP15[data_France$X.13CTP15>7.01 | data_France$X.13CTP15<0.99]<-NA


data_France$X.14CTP1[data_France$X.14CTP1>7.01 | data_France$X.14CTP1<0.99]<-NA
data_France$X.14CTP2[data_France$X.14CTP2>7.01 | data_France$X.14CTP2<0.99]<-NA
data_France$X.14CTP3[data_France$X.14CTP3>7.01 | data_France$X.14CTP3<0.99]<-NA
data_France$X.14CTP4[data_France$X.14CTP4>7.01 | data_France$X.14CTP4<0.99]<-NA
data_France$X.14CTP5[data_France$X.14CTP5>7.01 | data_France$X.14CTP5<0.99]<-NA
data_France$X.14CTP6[data_France$X.14CTP6>7.01 | data_France$X.14CTP6<0.99]<-NA
data_France$X.14CTP7[data_France$X.14CTP7>7.01 | data_France$X.14CTP7<0.99]<-NA
data_France$X.14CTP8[data_France$X.14CTP8>7.01 | data_France$X.14CTP8<0.99]<-NA
data_France$X.14CTP9[data_France$X.14CTP9>7.01 | data_France$X.14CTP9<0.99]<-NA
data_France$X.14CTP10[data_France$X.14CTP10>7.01 | data_France$X.14CTP10<0.99]<-NA
data_France$X.14CTP11[data_France$X.14CTP11>7.01 | data_France$X.14CTP11<0.99]<-NA
data_France$X.14CTP12[data_France$X.14CTP12>7.01 | data_France$X.14CTP12<0.99]<-NA
data_France$X.14CTP13[data_France$X.14CTP13>7.01 | data_France$X.14CTP13<0.99]<-NA
data_France$X.14CTP15[data_France$X.14CTP15>7.01 | data_France$X.14CTP15<0.99]<-NA

data_France$X.15CTP1[data_France$X.15CTP1>7.01 | data_France$X.15CTP1<0.99]<-NA
data_France$X.15CTP2[data_France$X.15CTP2>7.01 | data_France$X.15CTP2<0.99]<-NA
data_France$X.15CTP3[data_France$X.15CTP3>7.01 | data_France$X.15CTP3<0.99]<-NA
data_France$X.15CTP4[data_France$X.15CTP4>7.01 | data_France$X.15CTP4<0.99]<-NA
data_France$X.15CTP5[data_France$X.15CTP5>7.01 | data_France$X.15CTP5<0.99]<-NA
data_France$X.15CTP6[data_France$X.15CTP6>7.01 | data_France$X.15CTP6<0.99]<-NA
data_France$X.15CTP7[data_France$X.15CTP7>7.01 | data_France$X.15CTP7<0.99]<-NA
data_France$X.15CTP8[data_France$X.15CTP8>7.01 | data_France$X.15CTP8<0.99]<-NA
data_France$X.15CTP9[data_France$X.15CTP9>7.01 | data_France$X.15CTP9<0.99]<-NA
data_France$X.15CTP10[data_France$X.15CTP10>7.01 | data_France$X.15CTP10<0.99]<-NA
data_France$X.15CTP11[data_France$X.15CTP11>7.01 | data_France$X.15CTP11<0.99]<-NA
data_France$X.15CTP12[data_France$X.15CTP12>7.01 | data_France$X.15CTP12<0.99]<-NA
data_France$X.15CTP13[data_France$X.15CTP13>7.01 | data_France$X.15CTP13<0.99]<-NA
data_France$X.15CTP14[data_France$X.15CTP14>7.01 | data_France$X.15CTP14<0.99]<-NA
```

Comment: The best way [to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) is to show your current data, sample code and expected output. While sample code alone is good, it leads to an XY problem and possible solutions might be missed. See how to improve your post: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example). Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Base R equivalent of @Cettt's answer:

```
## helper function to replace elements with NA
rfun <- function(x) replace(x, which(x<0.99 | x>7.01), NA)
## identify which columns need to be changed
cnm <- grep("^X.[0-9]+CTP[0-9]+", names(data_France))
for (i in cnm) {
    data_France[cnm] <- rfun(data_France[cnm])
}
```

You could also use `lapply()`, but sometimes the `for` loop is easier to understand and debug.

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend the `dplyr` package which has the `mutate_at` function.
In your case you could use it like this:

```
library(dplyr)
data_France %>% 
  as_tibble %>% 
  mutate_at(vars(matches("^X.[0-9]+CTP[0-9]+")), ~ifelse(.x < 0.99 | .x > 7.01, NA_real_, .x))
```

Answer (score 2):

```
#Create a vector of variable names. There may be other ways to do this, like using
#regex or just taking the indices of the variables names (e.g., 1:225)

vars <- apply(expand.grid("X.", as.character(1:15), "CTP", as.character(1:15)), 
              1, paste0, collapse = "")

for (i in vars) {
  data_France[[i]][data_France[[i]] > 7.01 | data_France[[i]] < 0.99] <- NA
}
```

If this is your entire data set (i.e., there are no other variables in the data), you can simply do

```
data_France[data_France > 7.01 | data_France < 0.99] <- NA
```